# jQuery Ajax loop data show one by one

Tags: jquery, ajax, fadein

I'm using `append` on jquery. I want to show the data one by one, first show loading image for 5 seconds then fade in the data badge id from big size font to small.

Any clues on how to do that?

```html
<div class="loading">
  <img src="https://loading.io/spinners/mac/lg.mac-fan-spinner.gif" />
  <div class="setBadgeID"></div>
</div>
```

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "getDraw",
  type: "POST",
  data: { ID: ID },
  dataType: "JSON",
  success: function(jsonStr) {
    $('.loading').show();
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonStr.badgeID.length; i++) {
      var num = i + 1;
      var badgeID = jsonStr.badgeID[i];
      $('.setBadgeID').append(badgeID).fadeIn('slow');
    }
  }
});
```

```php
$ID = $_POST['ID'];

$qTotalLuckyDraw = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tbl_lucky_draw WHERE lucky_draw_id = '" . $ID . "'");
$dTotalLuckyDraw = mysqli_fetch_array($qTotalLuckyDraw);

$getTotalLuckyDraw = $dTotalLuckyDraw['total_draw'];
$getLuckyDrawID = $dTotalLuckyDraw['lucky_draw_id'];

$qGetLuckDraw = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tbl_employee_attend WHERE flag = 'N' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT $getTotalLuckyDraw");
while($dGetLuckDraw = mysqli_fetch_array($qGetLuckDraw))
{
    $badgeID[] = $dGetLuckDraw['badgeid'];
    $update = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE tbl_employee_attend SET flag = 'Y', lucky_drawid_fk = '" . $getLuckyDrawID . "' WHERE badgeid = '" . $dGetLuckDraw['badgeid'] . "'");
}

$data = array(
    'badgeID' => $badgeID,
    'totalLuckyDraw' => $getTotalLuckyDraw,
    'totalEmployeeLuckyDraw' => $getTotalLuckyDraw
);

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Aside from the question, note that your SQL statement is wide open to injection attacks. Research how to improve it by using prepared statements

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan noted

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
     $('.loading').show();  
$.ajax({
  url: "getDraw",
  type: "POST",
  data: { ID: ID },
  dataType: "JSON",
  success: function(jsonStr) {
    $('.loading').hide();
   console.log("jsonStr" , jsonStr);
   for (var i = 0; i < jsonStr.length; i++) {
                   console.log("jsonStr[i]" , jsonStr[i]);
                  $('.setBadgeID').append(jsonStr[i]).fadeIn('slow');
                }
  }
});
```

Comment: Not working, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'badgeID' of undefined`

Comment: try two comments `console.log("jsonStr" , jsonStr);` or  `console.log("jsonStr" , JSON.parse(jsonStr));`. update the output

Comment: Here is the result `badgeID: Array(20)
0: "L18C113"
1: "100702"
2: "L18K031"
3: "L18G104"
4: "130706"
5: "080405"
6: "L18F077"
7: "090805"
8: "L18K010"
9: "L18E008"
10: "L18F017"
11: "L18H038"
12: "080109"
13: "040932"
14: "L18D077"
15: "L18J046"
16: "L18K029"
17: "L18G123"
18: "L18G128"
19: "L18J003"
length: 20`

Comment: Hey @HiDayurieDave please let me know, which console your get the above output

Comment: this `console.log("jsonStr" , jsonStr);`

Comment: got error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199725/discussion-between-hidayurie-dave-and-senthil).

Comment: `$('.setBadgeID').append(jsonStr[i]).fadeIn('slow');` try this code only. it's working fine

Comment: `$('.setBadgeID').append('<div>'+jsonStr[i]+'</div>').fadeIn('slow');` try now

Comment: after success you can use `$('.loading').hide();`. I updated latest code and try once